# Does specifying brackets for 1D arrays like [[ ]] make any change in the structure?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Does this `p = np.array(`**[[**`mu, sig`**]]**`)` make any change than just specifying `np.array(`**[**`mu, sig`**]**`)`?

Comment: if you specify brackets like you have mentioned in your question, it comes 2D array, isn't it?

Comment: You can verify by yourself by checking their shapes with  with `np.array([[mu, sig]]).shape` and `np.array([mu, sig]).shape`.

Comment: Another way to think about it is "How do I get the value of `mu` accessing `p` by its indices?" for both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, there is a difference between the two expressions.**

`[mu, sig]` is an array with two elements (`mu` and `sig`).

`[[mu, sig]]` is an array with one array inside it. That one array is `[mu, sig]`, an array with two elements (`mu` and `sig`). So `[[mu, sig]]` is a two dimensional array (i.e. an array of arrays).

**Edit:** I originally said that `[[mu, sig]]` is an array with one element inside it. While that is the way I think about multi-dimensional arrays, it sparked a discussion in the comments because that is not 100% correct. `[[mu, sig]]` still has two elements, only that they are organized in a two dimensional fashion.

Saying that `[[mu, sig]]` has one element would be like saying that the following matrix has only two elements:

```
[ [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6] ]
```

In light of this, and in order not to confuse anyone, I've edited my answer to clarify: `[[mu, sig]]` is an array with one array inside it. It is not fully correct to say that it has only one element inside it.

Comment: In numpy both are arrays with two elements. It's the shape that's different.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, not really. If their shapes are different, they ARE different things. See my comment on the OP about accessing the elements on both types of arrays. If we move that to math, one is a row matrix and another is a column matrix.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I guess not. Try `len(np.array([1, 2])` and `len(np.array([[1, 2]])`.

Comment: I've missed closing parenthesis on my previous comment. What I meant to say is "try `len(np.array([1, 2]))` and `len(np.array([[1, 2]]))`".

Comment: `len` gives the first dimension, not the number of elements.

Comment: I think this is a valid discussion. While I think of `[[1,  2]]` as an array with one element, it would be like saying that `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` has only two elements inside it. It is not fully correct specially when we're talking about matrixes in a mathematical way. I've edited my answer, thanks to all of you!